# char* to char[]

Tags: c++

I have char* which is of fixed (known) width but is not null terminated.

I want to pass it into `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR("Bad string " << char_pointer);` but as its not null terminated it will print it all.

Any suggestions of some light weight way of getting  `"(char[length])*char_pointer"` without performing a copy?

Comment: All strings have to be null terminated. No conversion will help. You need to manually add the `'\0'` character.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Well that's just not true, is it. The real problem is that there is no valid conversion from a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Tomalak With the exception of `sizeof()` arrays and pointers are effectively indistinguishable.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Complete rubbish. (a) They are completely different kinds of types, as the lack of the conversion matt desires demonstrates. (b) Consider `float**` vs `float[x][y]`. Think these are compatible? You're wrong. (c) Arrays are **NOT** pointers. Don't be led astray by the decay of array variables into pointers-to-the-first-element-of-an-array when you attempt to pass by value into a function.

Comment: @Tomalak (a) There is no conversion involved in the question. (b) Of course they are not compatible, that's like saying that `int x[];` and `float x[];` are compatible. But `float** x;` is compatible with `float* x[];` and `float x[a][b];` is compatible with `float (*x)[a];` (c) Array are implicitly convertible to a pointer to the first element and that doesn't only apply to function calls.

Comment: @Tomalak: In this case, the `char[length]` array is going to decay into a `char*` as soon as it gets passed to `operator<<` anyway. So the problem is null termination. (And even if it didn't decay, you'd need a template specialization of `operator<<` to have a version that could use the array length.)

Comment: @KenBloom: True, using the hypothetical new array variable would also be problematic. Fortunately I guess he can't obtain it in the first place. :)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the case in your logging library, but sometimes libraries that implement streams (like the iostreams library) implement a `write(char*, streamsize)` function that can handle this case easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Real `iostream`s

When you're writing to a real iostream, then you can just use `ostream.write()` which takes a `char*` and a size for how many bytes to write -- no null termination necessary. (In fact, any null characters in the string would be written to the ostream, and would not be used to determine the size.)

## Logging libraries

In some logging libraries, the stream that you write to is not a real iostream.  This is the case in [Log4CPP](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/).

However, in [Log4CPlus](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/) which is what it appears matt is using, the object that you're writing to is a `std::basic_ostringstream<tchar>` (see `loggingmacros.h` and `streams.h` for the definition, since none of this is obvious from the documentation). There's just one problem: in the macro `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR`, the first `<<` is already built into the macro, so he won't be able to call `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR(.write(char_pointer,length))` or anything like that. Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way around this without deconstructing the `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR` error macro and getting into the internals of Log4CPlus

## Solution

I'm not sure why you're trying to avoid copying the string at this point, since you can see that there's a lot of copying going on inside the logging library. Any attempt to avoid that extra string copy is probably unwarranted optimization.

I'm going to assume that it's an issue of code cleanliness, and maybe an issue of making sure the copy happens inside the `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR` macro, as opposed to outside it. In that case, just use:

```
LOG4CPLUS_ERROR("Bad string " << std::string(char_pointer, length));
```

Comment: Thanks ken, Cleanliness was a big part of what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

No, you'll have to deep-copy and null-terminate it. That code expects a null-terminated string and it means a contiguous block of characters ending with a null terminator.

Comment: ..simplest is to construct a `std::string` with the `const char*` and the `size_t`, unless you can get access to the underlying stream object.

Comment: Yeah I guess even a char[] would need to be null terminated.

Comment: @matt: That, or you'd need to be able to pass the length to whatever function you're calling.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to print such a string, you could:

1. Store the last byte.
2. Replace it with \0.
3. Print the string.
4. Print the stored byte.
5. Put the stored byte back into the last position of the string.

Wrap all this in a function.

Answer (score 2):

We're getting hung up on the semantics of conversion between `char*` and `char[]`. Take a step back, what are you trying to do? If this is a simple case of on an error condition, streaming out the content of a structure to a stream, why not do it properly?

e.g.

```
struct foo
{
  char a1[10];
  char a2[10];
  char a3[10];
  char a4[10];
};

// free function to stream the above structure properly..
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& str, foo const& st)
{
  str << "foo::a1[";
  std::copy(st.a1, st.a1 + sizeof(st.a1), std::ostream_iterator<char>(str));
  str << "]\n";

  str << "foo::a2[";
  std::copy(st.a2, st.a2 + sizeof(st.a2), std::ostream_iterator<char>(str));
  str << "]\n";

  :

  return str;
}
```

Now you can simply stream out an instance of `foo` and don't have to worry about null terminated string etc.!

Comment: matt doesn't have the advantage of using iostreams here. He's got a logging library that uses its own class that doesn't descend from iostreams, so he'd have to write his own ostream_iterator. But given that your solution uses iostreams, why don't you just use `ostream.write(char*, streamsize)`?

Comment: @Ken, sure, that's just as easy, I was going for the full blown algorithms based approach! ;) Interesting, surely the log4cpp stuff implements some form of object derived from `std::ostream`?

Comment: see the answer I've now written. It's complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I keep a string reference class in my toolkit just for these type of situations. Here is a greatly abbreviated version of that class. I trimmed away anything that is not relevant to this particular problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class stringref {
public:
    stringref(const char* ptr, unsigned len) : ptr(ptr), len(len) {}

    unsigned length() { return len; }
    const char* data() { return ptr; }

private:
    const char* ptr;
    unsigned len;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, stringref sr) {
    const char* data = sr.data();
    for (unsigned len = sr.length(); len--; )
        os << *data++;
    return os;
}

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "string: " << stringref("test", 4) << endl;
}
```

or, in your case:

```
LOG4CPLUS_ERROR("Bad string " << stringref(char_pointer, length));
```

should work.

The idea of a string reference class is to keep enough information about a string (a size and a pointer) to refer to any block of memory which represents a string. It relies on you to make sure that the underlying string data is valid throughout the lifetime of a stringref object. This way you can pass around and process string information with a minimum of overhead.

Comment: matt doesn't have the advantage of iostreams, but you do. Why wouldn't you just use `ostream.write(char*, streamsize)`?

Comment: I haven't used log4c++, but syntax of the example lead me to believe that it uses iostreams internally. LOG4CPLUS_ERROR("Bad string " << stringref(char_pointer, length)) should work.

Comment: @Ferruccio: Log4cpp doesn't -- it overloads `operator<<` on its own class that has no relationship to iostreams. Looking more at Log4Cplus, which is what matt is using, I'm can't tell from the documentation whether it uses iostreams, but the code examples lead me to think that it actually does.

Comment: A quick search of the log4c++ source relevealed that it uses stringstreams internally to buffer the output. So you can use iostreams. However, you still can't use ostream::write() because you don't have direct access to the stringstream object. The macro relies on you using operator<< to write everything.

Comment: I didn't realize that log4c++ and log4cplus were two different libraries. My references to "log4c++" should be read as "log4cplus".

Answer (score 0):

When you know it is of fixed length: Why not simply add one more charakter to the size of the array? Then you can easily fill this last char with \0 terminating character and all will be fine

Comment: And how does he do this without a copy?

Comment: When allocationg the memory just use (knownsize) + 1, and after filling the data in the array just do a data[knownsize] = '\0';

Comment: If he could do that, he could make his C-string work properly in the first place. This question is about working around the _lack of ability to do this_.

Comment: Maybe he didn't know it can simply add a terminating char this way ;) Anyways, when he says the size of the data is known I do not see any reason why he cannot allocate one more char.

Comment: Known isn't the same as changeable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to copy it. There is no proper conversion in the language that you can use to get the array type out of it.

It seems very odd that you want to do this, or that you have a non-terminated C-style string in the first place.

Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: ...and even if you could, there's no support (AFAIK) of directly streaming out the array anyway (without using `std::copy`). Best bet is to construct a `std::string()`, using the variant that takes a `const char*` and a `size_t` and stream that...

Comment: The char* is to a char[] within a struct full of char[]s.  The full struct works as 1 record and even a char[].  Not ideal for my position but useful elsewhere

Comment: @matt: OK. Well, the answer stands. :) Copy it, ideally by constructing a `std::string` out of it with the details that Nim mentioned.